# Class versioning

Tags: vb.net, versioning

I'm looking for a clean way to make incremental updates to my code library, without breaking backwards compatibility. This could mean adding new members to classes, or changing existing members to provide additional functionality. Sometimes I am required to change a member in such a way that it would break existing code (e.g. renaming a method or changing its return type), so I'd rather not touch any of my existing types once they are shipped.

The way I currently set this up is through inheritance and polymorphism by creating a new class that extends the previous "version" of that class.

[image: class diagram]

The way this works is by creating the appropriate version of `StatusResult` (e.g. `StatusResultVersion3`), based on the actual value of the `ProtocolVersion` property, and returning it as an instance of `CommandResult`.

Because .NET does not seem to have a concept of class versioning, I had to come up with my own: appending the version number to the end of the class name. This will no doubt make you cringe. I could easily imagine yourself scratching your eyes out after zooming in on the diagram. But it works. I can add new members and override existing members, without introducing any code breaking changes.

Is there a better way to version my classes?

Comment: so then you you havesome sort of  `StatusResutlFactoryVersion3` that returns `StatusResultVersion3` as `StatusResult`?

Comment: Yep, all of the CommandResult types are basically just thin wrappers around an XML document which I get from a webservice. Whenever a command is executed using my custom `HttpClient` I return an instance of the appropriate CommandResult type depending on the HTTP response headers.

Comment: So mainly because the webservice can be of an earlier version than my code was built for, I need to ensure that I keep my types backwards compatible.

Comment: I think this could be done with Interface. One class, multiple interface for each version.

Comment: I don't know. I don't think that deals with the initial problem where a member can be changed throughout versions to return different results.

Comment: Actually I think I got it! I can create a version2 interface that extends a version1 interface and mark modified methods with the `Shadows` keyword.

Comment: @StevenLiekens Your idea works well, i cannot think of a better way of handling this :)

Comment: @Naval In the end, I went with the interfaces idea because it allows me to keep multiple versions of a class member in a single class file. When I need to update the class, I'll just add the new interface, shadowing the member that has been changed, and change the return type on some of my methods. This works without breaking backwards compatibility because of polymorphism.

Comment: @StevenLiekens It mighht help people who come looking for this sort of information in the future if you wrote up your solution and answered your own question.  It will also make it drop off the unanswered questions list :)

Answer (score 1):

There are typically two approaches when considering existing code and assembly updates:

1. [**Regression Testing**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_testing)

   This is a great approach for non-breaking changes, where you can simply overload functions to provide new parameters, etc. Visual Studio has some very advanced [unit testing capabilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264975.aspx) to make your regression testing relatively easy and automated.
2. [**Assembly Versions**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51ket42z.aspx)

   If your changes are going to start breaking things, like rewriting the way some utility works, then it's time for a new assembly version. .NET is very good about working with assembly versions. You can deploy the versioned assemblies to different folders so that existing code can continue to reference the old version while new code can take advantage of the features in the new version.

Comment: I didn't know that different assembly versions enable referencing what's basically the same library multiple times. Great tip!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with interfaces is that once published they're largely set in stone. To quote Anders Hejlsburg:

> ... It's like adding a method to an interface. After you publish an interface, it is for all practical purposes immutable, because any implementation of it might have the methods that you want to add in the next version. So you've got to create a new interface instead.

So you can never just update an interface, you need to create a completely new one. Of course, you can have a single class implement both interfaces so your maintainability effort is fairly low compared with (say) polymorphic classes where your code will become spread out between multiple classes over time.

Multiple Interfaces also allows you to remove methods in a way that classes do not (Sure, you can Deprecate them but that can result in very noisy intellisense after a few iterations)

I personally lean towards having entirely stand-alone versions of the interface in each assembly version.

That is to say...

#### v 0.1.0.0

```
interface IExample
{
    String DoSomething();
}
```

#### v 0.2.0.0

```
interface IExample
{
    void DoSomethingElse();
}
```

How you implement them behind the scenes is up to you, but most likely it'll be the same classes with slightly different methods doing similar jobs (otherwise, why use the same interface?)

All the old code should be referencing `0.1.x.x` and new code will reference `0.2.x.x`. About the only issue is when you find (say) a security flaw and the fix needs to be back-ported to an earlier version. This is where a decent VCS comes in (Personal preference is TFS but SVN or anything else which supports branching/merging will do).

Merge the fixes from the `0.2` branch back into the `0.1` branch and then do a recompile to result in (say) `0.1.1.0`.

As long as you stick to a process like this:

- Major or Minor build will increment if there are any breaking changes (aka signatures will not change on Build/Revision increments)
- Use [publisher policies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19.aspx) if the new Major/Minor version should be used by older programs (equivalent to guaranteeing nothing broke so use the new version anyway)
- References in client apps should point at a Major/Minor version but not specify revision/build

This gives you:

- A clean codebase without legacy clutter
- Allows clients to use the latest version with no code changes if nothing has broken
- Prevents clients using newer versions of an assembly which do have breaking changes until they recompile (and, one hopes, update their code as appropriate to take advantage of the new features.)
- Allows you to release security patches for previous versions

Comment: Not terribly important, but if an app has DLLs for both v0.1 and v0.2: can it choose which version of `IExample` to use at run-time?

One of the things that I like about having new interfaces extend older interfaces is the ability cast an object to whatever version interface I want to use.

Comment: Yes and no... If the assembly is referenced directly as per usual, then no - the names will clash, however you can create an `AppDomain`, load the appropriate assembly into it and then use reflection to get a reference to the appropriate `IExample` - But then you'd have to load one assembly or another, the name has to be unique within the AppDomain

Answer (score 0):

The OP solved his problem as indicated by [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15073924/class-versioning/16751900#comment-23606127):

> In the end, I went with the interfaces idea because it allows me to keep multiple versions of a class member in a single class file. When I need to update the class, I'll just add the new interface, shadowing the member that has been changed, and change the return type on some of my methods. This works without breaking backwards compatibility because of polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

If this is mainly for serialization, This can be achieved in .Net using DataContractSerializers and DataAnnotations. They can deserialize different versions an object into the same object to allow for different versions of the same class to be deserialized, leaving any properties it can't map blank.

Comment: The purpose is allowing library classes to change over time without breaking code that depends on them.